# Stasheff's operad as a relative W-construction

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

Lets work in the compactly generated topological spaces category. Let K be the Stasheff's operad (which algebras are $A_\infty$-spaces with strict unit). Please, I would like to understand how K can be given as the relative W-construction $W(I^* \to As)$, where $I^*$ is the operad of pointed spaces and As is the operad of unital monoids.

More precisely, I would like to know what are the specific identifications involving trees in $W(I^* \to As)$.

Comment: Could you describe or at least give a reference for the relative W-construction?

Comment: The generalized W construction (and its relative version) is given by Berger and Moerdjik in the paper. "The Boardman-Vogt resolution of operads in monoidal model categories".

Comment: If that's your reference, be aware that there is an error in the relative construction in that paper: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44166/how-does-berger-moerdijks-relative-boardman-vogt-work

Comment: Thank you. But anyway I do not see how the identifications "kills" stumps (with over the "lollipop") in the particular case above in order get the associahedra via trees construction.

Comment: You are correct. That relative $W$-construction, using Berger--Moerdijk, yields infinite dimensional spaces in each arity and certainly does not give the polytopes $K$. In fact, because there is no composition in the operad $I*$ (except with the identity in ${I*}(1)$), the relative-$W$ construction coincides with the ordinary $W$ construction for $As$, which certainly does not give the associahedra because of the unit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Berger-Moerdijk's relative Boardman-Vogt work?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44166/how-does-berger-moerdijks-relative-boardman-vogt-work)

Comment: Thank you Gabriel, that was my suspicious. I needed show that any A-infty space with strict unit was canonically a A-infty space with homotopy units (wich is expected). But I think it can be done via an explicit quotient of WAs killing stumps (with over the lollipop). Then the quotient operad map arises a restriction functor between algebras. Actually it is just to mime the things for the bicoloured operad Act of left monoid actions.